# Unable to detect class level custom annotation in Spring AOP

Tags: java, reflection, tomcat7, spring-aop

I am trying to intercept classes in Spring with following settings

**Interceptor**

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyInterceptor {

    @Around("execution(* com.example.services..*(..))")
    public Object intercept(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        if (pjp.getTarget() != null && pjp.getTarget().getClass().getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class) != null) {
            System.out.println("Yes annotation present");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Annotation not present");
        }

        return = pjp.proceed();
    }   
}
```

and the **class** being intercepted is as follows

```
@Component
@MyAnnotation
public class MyAlert implements IAlert {

}
```

Every thing is working fine until and unless I make the following changes

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "file:${catalina.home}/conf/my.properties" })
@Component
@MyAnnotation
public class MyAlert implements IAlert {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
}
```

I wanted to read properties located in conf folder of tomcat7, after making these changes my interceptor is unable to read my custom annotation `@MyAnnotation`. it says (custom message written in interceptor)

> Annotation not present

and here is custom annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {

}
```

I really want the class should be intercepted and annotation must be detected on class if it is annotated. I also want to read properties from conf folder in that intercepted class.

Comment: did you try with the xml configuration for property injection viz. `<context:property-placeholder location="file:${catalina.home}/conf/my.properties" />` and `@Value` annotation ?

Comment: nope I havent, because I am using Annotations and NOT xml based configurations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your check for the annotation fails because you are checking on the dynamic proxy's type instead of the actual annotated class's one. You can work around it like this:

```java
pjp.getSignature().getDeclaringType().getAnnotation(RestController.class) != null
```

Comment: but there is one confusion If remove this `@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "file:${catalina.home}/conf/my.properties" })` it works fine

Comment: Must be the inner workings of Spring AOP and CGLIB or Java dynamic proxies, respectively. I have not looked into that. I just presented you with a viable solution. I would appreciate if you accepted it because I checked that it does indeed work.